# E501 line too long (99 > 79 characters)

Tags: python, linux

I execute a linux shell command using python.

I get the below error for the line mentioned-

```
E501 line too long (99 > 79 characters)
```

Code:

```
 ssh_client.exec_command(
            "sudo grep 'cpu ' /proc/stat | awk '{usage=($2+$4)*100/($2+$4+$5)} END {print usage}'")
```

Im not sure how to format the line as its a Linux command.

Comment: Not related to the answer, but you don't need `sudo` to query `/proc/stat` on a typical linux distro. Also, you can save one process execution by doing just `awk '/cpu / {usage=.....}' /proc/stat`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consecutive string literals (separated only by whitespace) are merged into one in Python. So:

```
ssh_client.exec_command(
    "sudo grep 'cpu ' /proc/stat | "
    "awk '{usage=($2+$4)*100/($2+$4+$5)} END {print usage}'")
```

Answer (score 6):

The shell command isn't returning an error. What's happening is you have a type of source code analysis tool called a linter (specifically in this case, it looks like [flake8](https://flake8.readthedocs.org/en/2.4.1/) to me) that enforces compliance with Python best practices (a la PEP-8). PEP-8 specifies that lines of code should be 79 characters or less. Since that line is longer than 79 characters, the linter complains.

If in a given case you find that conforming to PEP-8 or other established community best practices makes your code less readable, you can mark a line of code `# noqa` to tell the linter to ignore it:

```
some_gnarly_line_of_code()  # noqa
```

minitech's answer is the right one in this case, but it is helpful to be aware that in special cases you have the latitude to work around linter complaints that break the build!